# Eliminar elemento x de una lista - Recursividad

Tags: c++

Tengo que crear una función que elimine de una lista todos los elementos con dato numérico `x`.

Mi Código:

```
struct nodolista {
    int elem;
    nodolista *sig;
};

typedef nodolista *lista;

void remover(int x, lista l) {
   if (l != NULL) {
      remover(x, l->sig);
      if (l->elem == x)
         delete l;
   }
}
```

Pero no funciona correctamente, ya que cuando borra un elemento, el anterior a ese no se conecta con su siguiente. Esto lo sé hacer con modo iterativo, pero no de manera recursiva.

Comment: Dos pequeños apuntes: en C++ no es necesario escribir `typedef`. Por otro lado, a partir de C++11 puedes utilizar `nullptr` en lugar de `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haz la llamada recursiva que devuelva el siguiente, de este modo a la vuelta de la llamada recursiva lo puedes asignar al actual si no lo has eliminado. Es decir, al ir llamando al siguiente:

- Si es `null` devuelves `null` para asignarlo al anterior.
- Si es el que tienes que eliminar, asignas el siguiente a éste a un temporal (ya que lo vas a eliminar), lo eliminas, y haces la llamada recursiva con el siguiente.
- Si no lo tienes que eliminar asignas como el siguiente lo que devuelva la llamada recursiva del siguiente a éste.

O dicho de una forma más resumida:

- Si no eliminas el siguiente -> lo asignas.
- Si eliminas el siguiente -> asignas el siguiente que no vayas a eliminar (o `null` si ya no hay mas).

Te dejo el código de la función recursiva:

```
lista remover(int x, lista l) {

    if (l == NULL) {
        return l;       // Devolvemos NULL
    } else {
        if (l->elem == x) {
            lista tmp = l->sig; // Asignamos el siguiente a un temporal.
            delete l;           // Eliminamos el actual.
            return remover(x, tmp);   // Devolvemos lo que devuelva la llamada recursiva con el siguiente
        }
        else {
            l->sig = remover(x, l->sig);  // Asignamos lo que devuelva la llamada recursiva con el siguiente.
            return l;                     // Devolvemos el actual;
        }
    }
}
```

Espero haberme explicado, sino no dudes en comentar la respuesta e intendo explicarme mejor.

---

Como comenta @Xam Puedes usar `nullptr` en vez de `null` a partir de C++11.